# How to correctly exclude logging from TransactionScope in .Net

Tags: .net, logging, transactions, transactionscope

I have some code like this:

```
using (var scope = GetTransactionScope())
{
  ... do stuff
  InfoLogger.LogInformation("blah blah", "Blah blah", someEventId);
}
```

(NB: GetTransactionScope() gets me the transaction).

But I don't want to involve the logging call in the transaction; the `LogInformation()` call wraps a call to the Enterprise Libraries.

From what I understand I need to use the `Suppress` [TransactionScopeOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to exclude the logging call from the transaction (is that the only / best way)?

Assuming that's the case I'd rather do this inside my helper - otherwise I'm going to have a large SUV's worth of additional TransactionScope code all over the place...  So, is this the best way / acceptable:

```
public static void LogInformation(string title, string message, int eventId)
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    {
        ... do the real logging.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the `Suppress` option will mean that "do the real logging" happens outside of the transaction context.

But it depends a little bit on what you are logging and why; one other approach is to throw all your logging data onto a producer/consumer queue (i.e. a thread-safe queue serviced by a separate thread). Because `TransactionScope` is thread-bound this removes your transaction association, but it also has the advantage of removing the *logging* as a factor (latency etc) in the operation itself, and allows you to batch up the logging operations if you choose.

Obviously this would only apply to *informational* logging, as there is a chance (in edge cases) that a small amount of data from the queue will be lost during recycles etc.

The producer/consumer approach is *particularly* enticing if you are logging to a file, as it allows you to synchronize access to the file (which is obviously necessary), without the need to block on the IO itself (you are only synchronizing access to the queue).